# Cannot figure out why WebGL will not draw a triangle

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm not sure if this is proper protocol, but I have a project located at:

https://github.com/mkarbowski/angry-bears

Which is my attempt at a WebGL game. I have worked with OpenGL ES 2.0 with android so I figured that WebGL couldn't be too big of a leap. But the whole not being able to debug script is killing me. Let alone the lack of meaningful errors.

Comment: what do you mean not being able to debug script?

Comment: you gotta least point out where the triangle code is.

Comment: Ok, just glanced at your stuff. I applaud that you're writing your own GL wrapping engine, but really I've used three.js by mrdoob on a number of gaming projects and it is well throught out and robust.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well first off you're getting GL errors. It would probably good to figure out why.

You can use a "debug context" to find them. See [this entry in the WebGL Wiki](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Debugging)

I added included the file referenced there and added this line to your code in engine.js, line 26

```
gl = WebGLDebugUtils.makeDebugContext(gl, function(err, funcName, args) {
  throw WebGLDebugUtils.glEnumToString(err) + ": " + funcName;
});
```

In gltexture.js you have code like this

```
texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.texture);
```

this.texture is not defined. Maybe you meant to define it on the line before like this?

```
this.texture = gl.createTexture();
```

Then your onload callback for loading an image is using "this" but in the context of the callback there is no "this". The easiest way to fix that is to declare another variable "that" or make a property and use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

```
that = this;  // define that
image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
  loaded = true;
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, that.texture);  // using that
  return gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
};
```

That got rid of the errors

Following the code. The next thing, rather than check if the texture is loaded in GLUtils.useTexture I just added

```
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, 
                  gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                  new Uint8Array([255,0,0,255]));
```

To GLTexture so it always starts with a 1 pixel texture which will be replaced if and when the real texture loads.

Next up, your TriangleTest.draw is creating a buffer every frame. Probably not what you intended.

Then I started adding console.log things around your code. I changed the clear color to be random

```
 gl.clearColor(0, 0, Math.random(), 1);
```

That way I can see that the program is running.

I found out that the matrix you are passing in useCamera doesn't have a projection matrix. I set it to the identity and then changed the vertices so they were in clipspace just to get something in front of the screen. That got a black triangle.

So I looked at your your GLUtils.useTexture. In it you call texture.getTexture() which is a function that does not exist. Changing it to

```
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture.texture)
```

And now it renders something.

Other random comments

- Use the dev tools (in Chrome or Safari). Ctrl-Shift-J or Cmd-Shift-J or similar tools in Firefox
- Sometimes the [WebGL Inspector](http://benvanik.github.com/WebGL-Inspector/) can be helpful.
- console.log and console.error are your friend. console.error gives you a stack trace, at least in Chrome.
- Stop using setTimeout. Instead use [requestAnimationFrame](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/). One advantage, if your code dies it will stop. With setTimeout the browser will keep calling and calling making it hard to debug. Another advantage, it shows you care about your users by not DoSing their system when your page is not the front tab.
- It can be helpful to print and check all WebGL calls. Following the example of the debug context above it's easy to write a wrapper that (a) prints every call and (b) checks that there are no undefined parameters. (see [WebGL Wiki](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Debugging) for example)
- If you're using Chrome try Chrome 20 (Chrome Canary). It gives a few more error messages for WebGL errors. Firefox does as well.

Good luck with your project

Comment: I just got a chance to take a look and make all of these changes. It works like a charm now! This is my first time using javascript so I was making some embarassing mistakes. The debug output you added is amazing as well. Thanks so much!